# Why are some XML URI's recommended by the W3C?

Tags: xhtml

I dont know if my question would make sense but in the XML DTD, some websites use URI's that relate to W3.org sites, Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The DOCTYPE declaration on top of every HTML and XHTML documents defines the document type and the possible elements in the documents. They do this by referring to the DTD (Document Type Definition), which is nominally a file on the W3C website, w3.org.

Now in most cases, browsers don't even load the DTD off the W3C website. Although they're able to load and parse it (DTDs are written in SGML after all, a language all browsers know), they actually don't. They already know what's in it!
If it helps, think of it as being cached and pre-parsed.
Or to look at it in another way, the exact URL of the DTD is enough for the browser to know what is being meant. And since HTML5, specifying the DTD is actually optional; the browsers are smart enough to know what you mean even without saying which one explicitly.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes i know that the .dtd file is a file that declares the elements and syntax of the entire document, which is held in the W3 website, I know that the DTD itself is entirely useless, but all I want to know is why do websites trust the W3C website for holding a file that could just be privately held and protected incase of a mistake of the W3C's part which could possibly destroy the .dtd file and mess up the miltiple websites that are dependent on that possibly corrupted file? @MrLister

Comment: Because the W3C is the organisation that formally defines those things. Like I said, the browsers don't attempt to load the file; so it really doesn't matter if the w3.org site is down for maintenance or not.

Comment: You can actually create DTD files for use with your SGML based documents yourself. In XML for instance!